# Password for Redis with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: .net, stackexchange.redis

How do you specify the password for the Redis server with StackExchange.Redis? I am guessing you add it to the configuration string which is passed to the Connect method. I can't seem to find the format in which it needs to be specified.

Comment: @MarcGravell - The link you provided is broken meanwhile (404). The link in your answer still works. I recommend to remove it from the comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will add a full list of the key/value pairs to [the configuration docs](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration) tomorrow. Short version is: probably "foo,password=value". Longer version is: use `ConfigurationOptions` and set `.Password`. The document shows you how to switch between the two layouts.

Comment: So do I understand it correctly that if you have multiple password protected endpoints they need to use the same password? It's not possible to have one password per endpoint?

Comment: the working url is: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md

Comment: @balint close; it is actually: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration - the move to github pages is what broke the link

Answer (score 7):

This is the way I got it working (note that simply adding the password like `"localhost:6379,password=value"` didn't work for me - it needs to be set in the options):

```
var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse("localhost:6379"); // host1:port1, host2:port2, ...
options.Password = "yourPassword";      
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);

IDatabase conn = redis.GetDatabase();
```

Assuming that you're running it via:

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name yourRedisInstance redis --requirepass yourPassword
```

If the docker image wasn't run with a password, simply remove the line `options.Password = "yourPassword";` In that case, everyone can access the Redis service without a password (which you should not do if you have data in the cache that needs to be protected).

Answer (score 1):

I use this Connection string and it work fine for me:

```
127.0.0.1:6379,password=**********,ssl=False,abortConnect=False
```

Answer (score -3):

if you are using a local, you can use like this

```
"localhost, port:6379, password="YOUR_PASSWORD""
```

in server

```
"http://server, port:6379, password="YOUR_PASSWORD"
```