# StackExchange Redis ConnectionString

Tags: connection-string, stackexchange.redis

What is the full format of the ConnectionString used in StackExchange.Redis?

I have searched but cannot find documentation for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If in doubt, use the `ConfigurationOptions` class (which has properties etc) and `ToString()` it when you are ready to obtain the configuration-string. However, I suspect you are looking [for this](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration)

Comment: Yes, that's it! It's not obvious to me (and to search engines) that those items directly map to a connection string. I also see that configCheckSeconds is not in the list (I just finished decompiling it). Would you be open to me tweaking that section of the document?

Comment: Ah, I see now that "command string" is used elsewhere in the page.

Comment: FYI: link is broken. Another answer, the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23923545/5112433

Answer (score 1):

### Update.  The 'correct' answer links to crazy documentation.

There doesn't seem to be a [connect string](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/index.js#L1216)...

```
var client = redis.createClient(9000); // Open a port on localhost
var client = redis.createClient('/tmp/redis.sock'); // Open a unix socket
var client = redis.createClient(9000, 'example.com');
```

This, and options are documented on the [README](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#rediscreateclient).